# H placement of floats in tufte book

Tags: floats, tufte

I am using the *tufte-book* document class for writing a user manual. It involves many short code examples. I would like to achieve the following:

1. Being able to use [H] with the floats such that the caption will be displayed as usual in *tufte* at the side.
2. Having a new float environment that is just the same as figure, but its caption starts with *Example*. At the same time I would like to keep the option of having figures.

I tried to use the *figurerow* package for the [H] placement, but the captions are then part of the text, not on the side. The *newfloat* package can create an *Example* float, but does not recognize [H] at all. Any ideas please?

It should work like

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}
% ...
% all the preamble
% ...
\begin{example}[H]
\begin{lstlisting}
print "Hello World";
\end{lstlisting}
\caption{Hello world}
\end{example}
```

Comment: Welcome to TEX.SX. Could you please add a minimal working example?

Comment: Hi bmv, if I had a **working** example I wouldn't ask :) But I added an example of the expected syntax.

Comment: For getting familiar with MWEs, you might have a look at https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that